# Docker - symfony : file_get_contents failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: symfony, docker

I install Symfony on Linux container using docker.

But with time I get this error :

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(C:\Users\docker\Desktop\docker\TestBundle/Resources/views/404.html.twig):
>   failed to open stream: Invalid argument

with some search on the net, I search if the error is on permission, so I try this code :

```
if (is_writable($path)) {
  echo "The file is writable";
} else {
  echo "The file is not writable";
}
exit;
```

I get " The file is not writable ", I try all permission command but no one work.

is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with path separator of the host OS and container OS .Please share your Dockerfile so that people would help overcome this